# Change excerpt length according to the title length

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress is it possible to change the excerpt length depending on how long the title is?

I simply call the title like so:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

And the excerpt:

```
 <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // in my functions.php I set the length ?>
```

functions.php

```
function html5wp_index($length);
{
    return 25;

}
```

So if the title was 15 characters then the excerpt would only be 10 for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you.  Just place it in your functions.php file.  Currently it would affect all posts or pages where `the_excerpt();` is being used, but you could wrap it in a conditional to isolate it.  Just read the comments in the code for some further explanation of what's happening.

```
<?php

function aw_new_excerpt_length($length) {

    // get the post title and find its string length
    $str = get_the_title();
    $titleLength = strlen($str);

    // check if length is longer that 10 characters
    // and return an excerpt length for more or 
    // less than 10
    if($titleLength > 10) {
    return 5;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
}

// then add the filter to change the excerpt length
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'aw_new_excerpt_length');

?>
```

Just change the numbers to set it to your specification.

Comment: May be incorrect as I've not had this exact situation, but wouldn't you have to include `global $post;` to be able to use `get_the_title();` in a function?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but my answer works.  I tested it before posting.

Comment: Fair enough, WP usually kicks up a fuss in such instances!